# Translate SQL statement with inner joins to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have to make some queries in C# using LINQ. I tried my logic with a SQL request. It looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT test_laktationen.lom, test_laktationen.laktanfang, test_laktationen.laktende, b_milch_hms_diagnose.diagnose
FROM            test_laktationen INNER JOIN
                         b_milch_hms_diagnose ON test_laktationen.lom = b_milch_hms_diagnose.lom AND b_milch_hms_diagnose.behanddatum BETWEEN 
                         test_laktationen.laktanfang AND test_laktationen.laktende INNER JOIN
                         b_milch_hms_kalbung ON test_laktationen.lom = b_milch_hms_kalbung.lom AND test_laktationen.laktanfang = b_milch_hms_kalbung.kalbedatum
WHERE        (b_milch_hms_diagnose.diagnose LIKE '6.01.01.%' OR
                         b_milch_hms_diagnose.diagnose LIKE '6.01.02.%' OR
                         b_milch_hms_diagnose.diagnose LIKE '6.01.03.%' OR
                         b_milch_hms_diagnose.diagnose LIKE '6.01.04.%') AND (b_milch_hms_kalbung.gebverlauf = 3 OR
                         b_milch_hms_kalbung.gebverlauf = 4)
```

This works like it should, but now I have to make this request from data tables. Is this possible with LINQ? What would be good practice to solve this problem?

Comment: Are we to assume your using entity framework?

Comment: No not yet. I am currently using some SQLCommands and some LINQ statements in my application and I am likely to keep it this way for now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a data context to perform direct access. I would recommend Linq2Sql classes file (*.dbml) to get it started. Once you create your data structure in the Linq2Sql class with the server explorer, your linq statement would look something like:

```
var context = new MyLinq2SqlContext();

var results = (from lak in context.test_laktationen
    join milch in context.b_milch_hms_diagnose
        on lak.lom equals milch.lom
    join kalbung in context.b_milch_hms_kalbung 
        on lak.lom equals kalbung.lom and lak.laktanfang equals kalbung.kalbedatum
    where 
        (milch.diagnose.StartsWith("6.01.01") ||
        milch.diagnose.StartsWith("6.01.02") ||
        milch.diagnose.StartsWith("6.01.03") ||
        milch.diagnose.StartsWith("6.01.04")) &&
       (kalbung.gebverlaug == 3 || kalbung.geberlauf == 4) &&
       ((milch.behanddatum > lak.laktanfang && milch.behanddatum < lak.laktende) ||     (milch.behanddatum < lak.laktanfang && milch.behanddatum > lak.laktende))
    select new {
            lak.lom, 
            lak.laktanfang,
            lak.laktende,
            milch.diagnose
    }).Distinct();
```

This will probably require tweaking in the final "where" clause to make sure you get the "between" portion correct. `BETWEEN` doesn't translate natively into from Linq, but it can be coded in as long as you can predict which value is likely to be greater.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. This seems to be quite useful, but I still have some problems. I don't want to use a context in my function, because some of the tables don't really exist in the database. 'test_laktationen' e.g. is a data table that is created at runtime. And the needed values from the other tables I also want to load in data tables. Then I want to make this query with link an copy the data to a resulting data table. Is this possible?

Comment: If you don't want to use a context, then you'll have to bring the data down into `IEnumerable` objects. Then your context will become the objects themselves.

Comment: Yes you're right. I figured out how to do it now. Thanks a lot!